# Different sizes of the array depending on the flag values in Fortran 77

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77

I want to create a different array with different length and initialization depending on the flag value of some parameters I define.

However, I noticed that there are always an error if you try to define the array after the flag values are assigned to some parameters.

How do you over come this issue?

That is, I want to do something like

```
   PROGRAM CODE
   IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H, J-Z)
   INTEGER K1, K2
   COMMON / param  / flag

   flag=1

   if(flag.eq.1)
     DIMENSION array1(4), array2(6)
     DATA array1 /1,2,3,4/
     DATA array2 /1,2,3,4,5,6/
   elseif(flag.eq.2)
     DIMENSION array1(2), array2(3)
     DATA array1 /1,2/
     DATA array2 /1,2,3/
   endif
```

However, you get an error if DIMENSION is called after the execution "flag=1".
How do I overcome this problem and achieve what I desire?

Comment: Use tag fortran for all Fortran questions. Is it **really** necessery to use Fortran 77 in year 2017? This is very easy in Fortra 90 and later with Fortran 90. Even if the code was written in Fortran 77 you can use moder features with modern compilers and old code.

Comment: Also, if you have an error, you have to show it in your questions. We can try the code ourselves sometimes, but we may not have your compiler. See [ask].

Comment: `dimension` is a declaration statement and simply can't appear in an execution context, such as you have it.  *How do I overcome this problem and achieve what I desire?*  Program like it was 1999 and learn about `allocatable` arrays, which were introduced in Fortran 90.

Answer (score 0):

First some important advice: Don't use implicit type. Always use `IMPLICIT NONE` and declare all variables explicitly. Otherwise typos in variable names can lead to weird and hard-to-find bugs.

On to your question:

With Fortran 77 it's really hard. Your declaration statements **must** precede the execution statements. Both assignments and `if` statements are execution statements, and therefore can only be used **after** the declaration statements.

You asked about Fortran 77, so I'll give some info about Fortran 77 later, but first the obvious:

Use Fortran 90 or later!

Fortran 90 has allocatable statements, and allocations can happen during the execution:

```
program code
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: array1, array2
    integer :: flag

    flag = 1

    if (flag == 1) then
        allocate(array1(4))
        allocate(array2(6))
        array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    else
        allocate(array1(2))
        allocate(array2(3))
        array1 = [1, 2]
        array2 = [1, 2, 3]
    end if
    ...
end program code
```

If you really need Fortran 77, here are some ideas:

1. Use only part of the array

   ```
   integer array1(4), array2(6)
   data array1 /1, 2, 3, 4/
   data array2 /1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6/
   integer amax1, amax2
   integer flag

   flag = 1

   if (flag.eq.1) then
       amax1=4
       amax2=6
   else
       amax1=2
       amax2=3
   end if
   ```

   and then only use `array1(1:amax1)` and `array2(1:amax2)` in your code.
2. If your compiler has a preprocessor, you can use it. Of course this really means that you have to know which of the two paths you want to go at compile time.

   ```
         PROGRAM code
         IMPLICIT NONE
   #ifdef flag
         INTEGER array1(4), array2(6)
         DATA array1 /1, 2, 3, 4/
         DATA array2 /1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6/
   #else
         INTEGER array1(2), array2(3)
         DATA array1 /1, 2/
         DATA array2 /1, 2, 3/
   #endif
         PRINT *, array1, "size:", size(array1)
         PRINT *, array2, "size:", size(array2)
         END PROGRAM
   ```

   Save this as a source file with ending `.F` (capital F), and run it through the compiler with or without option `-D flag` and see what happens.

Comment: If using `[...]` for array constructors, why not use automatic allocation also?

Comment: I understood the question in the way that `flag` would be constant.

Comment: I have made changes as possible to the code to account for the fact that `flag` might change during runtime. (Of course it's not possible with the Preprocessor method.)